# Getting google recaptcha token for a test script

Tags: javascript, java, recaptcha, serenity-bdd, recaptcha-v3

I have a site with the following html code:

```
<div id="captchaDiv"></div>
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?onload=getCaptcha&render=explicit&sitekey=My_SITE_KEY"></script>
<script>
window.sd = function(token){ 
  document.writeln(token); 
}

getCaptcha = function(){
  window.captcha = grecaptcha.render('captchaDiv',{
    'sitekey' : My_SITE-KEY,
    'callback': windows.sd,
     'size':'invisible'
  })
}

function onPageLoad(){
  grecaptcha.ready(function(){ 
    grecaptcha.execute();
  });
}
window.onLoad(onPageLoad());
</script>
```

Now, when I browse and refresh this page, Google will provide a new token.

I have a test script as follow:

```
logger.info(RestAssured.get(page_url).then().extract().response().asString())
```

But instead of getting token, I am getting the page source code. Is there a way to this without creating a page to get the token?

Comment: What do you mean by "Google will provide a new token" ? You are supposed to have created an account for recaptcha and get a site key + secret key that aren't supposed to change.

Comment: Whenever I visit the page or refresh it shows some string token. This token is generated by Recaptcha API. The problem is I have to go the website to get that string and I am looking for a way to call the Recaptcha API directly from rest assured.

Comment: If what you are trying to do is to 'automate' reCaptcha validation you are doing what reCaptacha protects you against :/

Comment: I am trying to bind challenge programatically https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/invisible#programmatic_execute